# Memória insuficiente com ClientDataSet.SaveToFile

Tags: delphi, xml, firedac, tclientdataset, delphi-xe2

Eu preciso gerar um arquivo `XML` de uma tabela de 500.000 linhas e 200 colunas utilizando `ADQuery` do `FireDAC` e `TClientDataSet` gravando com

```
ClientDataSet.SaveToFile(Arquivo).
```

Eu preciso gravar com o `ClientDataSet` para permanecer a mesma estrutura do `XML`.

Meu código é:

```
ClientDataSet.Close;
Query.Sql.Clear;
Query.Sql.Add ("Select * from something");
ClientDataSet.Open;
ClientDataSet.SaveToFile("destination_folder.xml");
```

Mas ao salvar ocorre erro de memória insuficiente.

Como eu poderia gravar esse arquivo? Como poderia gravar o `ClientDataSet` em vários arquivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa Tarde,

Tente usar o componente FDMemTable do FireDAC no lugar do TClientDataSet e a FDQuery do FireDAC, ele também salva com a mesma estrutura e depois é só passar o caminho para receber o conteúdo. Com o seguinte código:

```
if (FDQuery.Active) then
    FDQuery.Close;
FDQuery.SQL.Clear;
FDQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM SOMETHING');
FDQuery.Open;
FDMemTable.Data := FDQuery1.Data;
FDMemTable.SaveToFile('destination_folder.xml');
```

Comment: Obrigado por sua dica @JRudolf, mas da mesma forma estourou a memória. Fiz a divisão da Query em selects menores e gravações de arquivos menores.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer paginação dos dados, por exemplo

se você tem 500.000 linhas(registros), você poder fazer paginação de 10.000 por vez, e automatiza, terminou os 10.000, faz o proximo e assim por diante.

Isso deixará o processo funcional e não usar toda a memória de vez.

Pode ser feito de N formas, um exemplo usando Macro **Firedac**

```
Procedure Paginar(Pagina,QtdLinha : Integer);
Const
  _sql = ' SELECT FIRST %D SKIP %D * FROM TABELA ';
Var
  sql : String;
begin
  sql := format(_sql,[qtdLinha,(Pagina-1*QtdLinha)]);
  Qry.Open(s);
end;
```

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo.